# Found a 2"x4" hole in return duct

Tags: hvac, attic

So this return duct in my attic has a perfectly cut 2"x4" hole in it. Why would someone have left that hole there? I live in southern Florida and the attic is usually 110-160F in the day time. This hole happens to be over a bathroom that doesn't have any exhaust vents so I wonder if it was someone's crazy idea for collecting humidity from the bathroom? I think this hole has been drawing dust from the attic into my home and making my AC work harder. Should I seal it?

Comment: So it sounds like you have a reasonable plan ("seal it"). What's the question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't ask a question.

Comment: Why it's there, we'll never know. Should it be there?, No, so just seal i up.

Comment: Could just be sloppy work. In my new house in Houston somebody measured wrong and left a 24" X 2" gap in AC duct work . It was not visible so they just left it.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact "Why would someone have left that hole there?"

Comment: @FreeMan "Why would someone have left that hole there?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like someone was planning on installing a return into the bathroom. A return is NEVER to be installed in a bathroom, so there wouldn't have been one, and you said there were also no exhausts, so they were probably about to put something in. Most people would not know that the exhaust is not a return, so they probably thought it was overlooked. Especially since the hole you described is the same size as what the exhaust duct would be (4" round), as opposed to any other return duct in the house, which would be more like 8"-20". The other possibility is that they were installing a fresh air intake. Was there a hole on a nearby wall or roof in the attic, leading to outside? Since it is "perfectly cut" I would not suspect rodents. Yes, you should seal it. Also, check your evap coils. You should clean them, since they are probably caked with debris now.

Comment: It wasn't round... more like rectangular but one side was 4". No other nearby holes. Thanks for your help.